# Python - Convert Dataframe to Dictionary where key is (row index, column name)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to convert a dataframe to a dictionary where the key is the row index and the column name of the dataframe and each key's value is the location of each row index and column name.

Let's assume this is my dataframe.

```
  1 2 3 
0 1 2 3
1 4 5 6
2 7 8 9
```

I want my dictionary to look something like this:

```
((0, 1), 1)
((0, 2), 2)
((0, 3), 3)
((1, 1), 4)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want dictionary or tuples?

Comment: @harvpan I think tuples could work too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex Series` with [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.stack().to_dict()
print (d)
{(0, 1): 1, (0, 2): 2, (0, 3): 3, 
 (1, 1): 4, (1, 2): 5, (1, 3): 6, 
 (2, 1): 7, (2, 2): 8, (2, 3): 9}
```

But if want `tuple`s:

```
s = df.stack()
L = list(zip(s.index.tolist(), s))
print (L)
[((0, 1), 1), ((0, 2), 2), ((0, 3), 3), 
 ((1, 1), 4), ((1, 2), 5), ((1, 3), 6),
 ((2, 1), 7), ((2, 2), 8), ((2, 3), 9)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! I meant to upvote and accept after the 20 minute timer, but got side-tracked along the way. :(